# Problem with json response in Python REST server I'm writing

Tags: python, ajax, json

For my own education I'm creating a simple daemon that will function as a REST server, listening on socket 9000.  For my first test I'm trying to do a REST call of simply doing a GET on http://localhost:9000/getsettings.json.

The simple server I hacked up gets the request OK, but I think there's a problem with the response it's sending.  I'm trying to send the response as JSON.  The code for the server socket is below.  Below that is the jQuery code I'm using to make the JSON request.  The print statement in the Python server does print a valid set of settings in JSON format.  Neither alert in the Javascript is being called when the page loads.  Any ideas?

```
Python:
    def socketThread(self):
        while 1:
            sock, address = self.serverSocket.accept()
            fs = sock.makefile()
            line = fs.readline();
            if line.startswith('GET /settings.json'):
                sock.sendall("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n")
                sock.sendall("Content-Type: application/json\r\n")
                settings = json.dumps(self.currentSettings) #, indent=4
                sock.sendall("Content-Length: " + str(len(settings)) + '\r\n\r\n')
                sock.sendall(settings)
                print settings
                sock.close()
```

Javascript:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/settings.json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(json){
            alert('json success ' + json);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
});

Answer (score 3):

You need to return a `200 OK` HTTP response and an empty line before sending your content.

You'll probably need some HTTP headers, too (`Content-type` would be an obvious one).

I would, however, recommend using one of Python's many HTTP libraries instead of implementing the protocol yourself.

Comment: I modified the python server to return the 200 OK and a JSON content type.  Using Firebug that seems to be getting returned ok, but the response body seems to be empty...

Comment: @fred - try to use the sendall method of Socket - send does not always send all the data provided.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I tried sendall but it didn't work any differently.  I am pretty sure the server side is sending back the data, as when I telnet to it then issue a GET /getsettings.json it gives me this response:

Comment: HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 56

{"netmask": "255.255.0.0", "ipaddress": "192.168.1.153"}

Answer (score 2):

Check that the server is actually being hit (eg, put an `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in your code. I found that jQuery executes the success callback with empty body when the server is not running (or listening on a different port...)

Comment: Yeah I checked, the python server is running and the socket is being connected to.  I also telneted to the server and it seems to send back the json content fine.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem was on the jQuery side, my request was being thwarted by the cross domain origin protection issue - my request was going to localhost on a different port so jQuery wasn't pulling down the data.  Now I need to figure out how to make that work.  Thanks for the help guys.